# How to pick out numbers $0,2\pmod 6$ with a root of unity (possibly sixth)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, roots-of-unity

Let $f(n)=ab^{-n}:\Bbb N\to\Bbb C^\times$

Find some $a,b\in\Bbb C^\times$ such that $f$ has the following properties:

1. $f(n)$ as a sequence indexed by $n$ has precisely two positive integer subsequences $f(6n)$ and $f(6n+2)$ and every other sequence $f(6n+x\in\{1,3,4,5\})$ contains no positive integers.
2. $f(x\in\{0,2\})=f(x+6)$

[question ends]

---

Here's as much as I can do.  For the ordered pair $(a,b)$, I have that:

Setting $(a,b)$ to be the primitive 2nd root of unity $(-1,-1)$ gives a sequence that alternates between positive integers and not: $f(n+2)=f(n)$.

So I suspect the solution involves generalising this idea by setting $b$ to be a primitive sixth root of unity.  I think this because there are exactly two primitive sixth roots of unity and they're separated by exponents $2$ mod $6$, as the solution requires.

Let $\phi$ be the primitive sixth root of unity.  Then some function $f$ which was was integer if and only if $\phi^{n-1}$ was a primitive root of unity would give us the required result. One approach I tried is letting $a=\phi^{-1}$ and $b=\phi$, but that doesn't quite work

Comment: Is $\;f\;$ a real function, a function on the integers, on the naturals...? What kind of numbers are $\;a,b, n\;$ ? Need to be more clear when asking.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what $\mathbb{C^\times}$ means, but I assume it's something like the set of complex numbers apart from $0$. Please correct me if this is inaccurate, especially if it affects the answer.

Assume that for some $a,b\in\Bbb C^\times$ your property $1$ holds for $n = 1$. Then you have, for some positive integers $m_1$ and $m_2$, that

$$f(6) = m_1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(8) & = f(6)(b^{-2}) \\
& = m_1(b^{-2}) \\
& = m_2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This gives that

$$b^{-2} = \frac{m_2}{m_1} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(10) & = f(8)(b^{-2}) \\
& = m_2\left(\frac{m_2}{m_1}\right) \\
& = \frac{m_2^2}{m_1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since $f(10)$ is not a positive integer (as $10 = 6(1) + 4$), this means $\frac{m_2}{m_1}$ is a positive rational, non-integral number. Thus, there's at least one prime factor $p$ of $m_1$ where $m_1$ has more factors of $p$ than $m_2$. Let $i$ be the number of these factors of $p$ in $m_1$, and $j$ be the number of factors of $p$ in $m_2$. Then we have

$$j \lt i \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Also, since \eqref{eq4A} is not a positive integer, we also have

$$2j \lt i \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

However, note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(12) & = f(10)(b^{-2}) \\
& = \left(\frac{m_2^2}{m_1}\right)\left(\frac{m_2}{m_1}\right) \\
& = \frac{m_2^3}{m_1^2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Property $1$ for $n = 2$ says this is a positive integer. This means that, regarding the factors of $p$ in the numerator and denominator,

$$3j \ge 2i \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

However, adding \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$3j \lt 2i \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

This contradicts \eqref{eq8A}, showing that property $1$ cannot hold.

Comment: Thanks for that. I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution! So you saved me a lot more. As for $\Bbb C^\times$, I was looking at the unit circle, so the only solutions would yield the sequences having $1$ as the only positive integer.

Comment: @samerivertwice You're welcome. Thanks for explaining what $\mathbb{C^{\times}}$  means. Is it considered to be standard notation? I don't consider myself an expert in dealing with complex numbers, but I've never seen that notation used before. Also, out of curiosity, where does the question come from?

Comment: I suspect I misused $\Bbb C^\times$. The question comes from me trying to engineer a topological closure to the positive integers, in which the sequences $S_n(x)=x+(1-2^{-n})2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ converge faithfully in the quotient $\Bbb N/\langle2,3\rangle$. As it is only two of six subsequences converge so I need the other 4 to go somewhere else.

Comment: P.S. I suspect you already know this but $^\times$ often means the multiplicative group of a ring, so your interpretation of $\Bbb C^\times$ makes more sense than the way I intended it. I should've said $S^1$ - although the plane minus the origin and the unit circle are both groups under multiplication. I'm pretty sure if there were any solutions, they would have been scalings of the sequence $\overline{1,0,1,0,0,0}$ which would have been the solution with $a,b\in S^1$ so it leaves the answer unchanged.